# Wordpress add wp_editor to custom_meta_box

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-boxes, wp-editor

Can please anyone help? I created custom meta boxes, two of them are in textarea.
This is what i have:

```
array(
        'label'=> 'Ingredients',
        'desc'  => 'List of ingrediends',
        'id'    => $prefix.'ingrediends',
        'type'  => 'textarea'
    ),
        array(
        'label'=> 'Directions',
        'desc'  => 'Directions',
        'id'    => $prefix.'directions',
        'type'  => 'textarea'
    )
```

==========================

```
case 'textarea':
    echo '<textarea name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" cols="60" rows="4">'.$meta.'</textarea>
        <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';
break;
```

How do i add wp_editor? I tried:

```
wp_editor( $content, 'recipe_directions', array( 'textarea_name' => 'recipe_directions', 'media_buttons' => false, 'tinymce' => array() ) );
```

But no luck. Can anyone help.
The whole idea is to make regular textarea like rich text editor

Thanks for your help .... anyone:)

Comment: well... this is disappointing.. anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather late than never.....

In your class init function (assuming it's a plugin class) add

```
add_meta_box(
    'ingredients_box_id',
    __( 'Ingredients', $this->textdomain ),
    array($this,'ingredients_box_content'),
    'ingredients_box',
    'advanced',
    'high'
);
```

Then add the function to enable the wp_Editor

```
function ingredients_box_content( $post )
{
    wp_editor( $meta_biography, 'ingredients_box_text_id', array(
        'wpautop'       => true,
        'media_buttons' => false,
        'textarea_name' => 'ingredients_box_text',
        'textarea_rows' => 10,
        'teeny'         => true
    ) );
}
```